# Set timezone for cron expressions

Tags: java, drools

I have seen that the CronExpression has a setter to define the timezone.

How can I set the value in drl file or when initializing the knowledge base?

Comment: This link can help in scheduling cron in Drools http://javadox.com/org.drools/drools-core/6.2.0.Final/org/drools/core/time/impl/CronExpression.html

Comment: But how can I find and edit the expressions?

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you give an example so that I can explain you better with the help of your example?

Comment: I have DRL files which make use of the cron expressions. In the docs I cannot find any information how to set the timezone in the drl files. But I know that the CronExpression class has the setter (you also pointed it out). So the question is: How can I find all CronExpressions or CronTriggers in my session and set the timezone.

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41041426/drool-rules-using-cron-expression